# Difference between loadSubScript and loadFrameScript in Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am aware that both these apis are used to inject Javascript into the webpage. Is there any difference between loadSubScript and loadFrameScript in Firefox extension development? In which situation would you use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are asking about [mozIJSSubscriptLoader.loadSubScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader#loadSubScript%28%29) and [nsIChromeFrameMessageManager.loadFrameScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChromeFrameMessageManager#loadFrameScript%28%29). These are two entirely different mechanisms with the only similarity being that both can load and execute code.

`mozIJSSubscriptLoader` isn't meant to load code into web pages - its primary goal is to load parts of your extension dynamically. This is a very old mechanism that even predates [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules).

The goal of `loadFrameScript()` is to load content scripts however, originally introduced to support multi-process setups ([e10s project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis)). It will load scripts that will run with the privileges of the web page in the context of the web page. No direct interaction with the code that loaded it is possible, only messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Most extensions don't have any reason to use loadFrameScript. It's target is [remote debugging](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/public/nsIMessageManager.idl).

Comment: Remote - yes. But why do you think that it has anything to do with debugging? The message manager was originally introduced for the setup where [multiple browser processes need to communicate](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis).